# complex blender collision efficiency

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, blender

I'm making a little project where you put a ball through a maze. I made a rounded corner so the ball would easily take corners. Here's the shape:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmuy3j1o7lvs413/Screenshot%202014-04-09%2023.25.25.png

Then I shape 6 different shapes around this one so that I can later give those 6 shapes Box Colliders in Unity

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dms7yqt0u71incq/Screenshot%202014-04-09%2023.26.22.png

**Now my question:**
When I import this in Unity and give the 6 added shapes box Colliders it works well.
BUT is there a better, more efficient way of giving a non-standard shape a complex collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is and it is called a `MeshCollider`. It creates the collider according to the original mesh. [Link to docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-MeshCollider.html).

Comment: Thank you @Esa. The MeshCollider didn't work because it was a 2D object that interacts with it. But with your help I found that the **polygon2D collider** works in the same way for 2D objects.